# Python: pandas read_sql_query

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Just started learning Pandas and tumbled over "read_sql_query":

In my code there are multiple create statements and executing them with "read_sql_query" is making the job redundant like:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 

con = sqlite3.connect("/Users/sqlite_example.db3")

query_1 = ("Create table temp_1")
pd.read_sql_query(query_1,con)

query_2 = ("Create table temp_1")
pd.read_sql_query(query_2,con)

query_3 = ("Create table temp_3")
pd.read_sql_query(query_3,con)
```

My questions are:

1. Can't all the queries be passed in single "pd.read_sql_query"
2. Can opening a connection with DB be avoided everytime i.e. con parameters once
   is not sufficient enough rather than to pass it everytime?

I tried looking into the documentations and web portals but couldn't came across anything like this. In the "read_sql_query" everytime the "query,con" has to be passed otherwise failing to do so is giving error.

Please help to understand the concept and way to pass multiple queries and establishing connection only one time rather than multiple times.

I hope this will help others also who might face similar  sort of issue innear future.

Comment: read_sql is for reading the result out from sql statement, for create query why do you want to read that in a dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

Note: `executelist()` is used to execute multiple sql statements in the same query.

```
con = sqlite3.connect("/Users/sqlite_example.db3")
cursor=con.cursor()

query_1 = "Create table temp_1;
           Create table temp_2;
           Create table temp_3;"

cursor.executelist(query)
```